# RaspberryPi MQTT broker maximum connections

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, iot, arduino-esp8266

I want to set up a system of 100-200 sensors that send their data (in a frequency of about 30 mins) to a MQTT broker based on RaspberryPi. Sensors data is obtained in an ESP8266, which would transmit via WiFi to the MQTT broker (which is in a distance of about 2 meters).

I wanted to know if is it possible for a broker of these characteristics to handle that many connections simultaneously.

Thank you so much!
Diego

Answer (score 0):

A single broker can handle many 1000s of clients.

The limiting factor is likely to be the size and frequency of message, but assuming the messages are not 10s of megabytes each then 200 messages spread of 30mins will be trivial.

Even if they are all grouped at the same time rough time (allowing for clock drift) then small messages will again not be a problem.